# How to add line feed between tests for console output in Rspec?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I have several tests that I run using Rspec.

The output looks something as follows:

```
returns an array containing partial words that have changed their case(upper/lower), 
and have matching partial words in opposite elements(ins/del)
returns an array containing words that have changed their case(upper/lower),
and have matching whole words in opposite elements(ins/del)
returns an array containing words that have changed their case(upper/lower), are at the start of a sentence, 
and have matching words in opposite elements(ins/del)
returns an array containing partial words that have changed their case(uppler/lower), have matching partial words in opposite elements(ins/del), 
and are preceded by an inserted word
```

I would like to have each tests separated by a line feed so that its easier for me to read the output.  I have tried adding "\n" and it does not seem to work.

Any ideas?

Comment: where did you try to put `\n`?

Comment: I put it at the end of the test description. Example it "returns an array...\n" do but this did not work

Comment: If it is in double quotes `"\n"` it should probably work...

Comment: I wish it did but it does not work.

Answer (score 1):

you can use ruby output command print or puts to get line feed between test
the difference between print and puts, print will not automatically give line feed but puts will give automatically
below is sample code

```
print "test = ", variable , ".\n"
puts  "test = ", variable
```

both of command above will give line feed after each command executed

Comment: where would I put this in an Rspec test?